# Camera preview freezes as well as stops recording audio (after one or few recordings)

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I've created a custom camera application using iOS - Swift. The problem is that that sometimes after I record with my phone, the camera preview freezes. More importantly, the camera also stops recording audio after I record a video once. I can't seem to understand whether this is a memory problem because the app memory doesn't show any issues. Here are the main snippets of code that might be the issue:

```
    func load_camera() {

        // Load the session
        capture_session = AVCaptureSession();
        capture_session?.beginConfiguration();
        capture_session?.usesApplicationAudioSession = true;
        capture_session?.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = true;
        capture_session?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
        camera_device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo);
        if(selfie) {
            guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.devices().filter({ $0.position == .Front })
                .first as? AVCaptureDevice else {
                    fatalError("No front facing camera found")
            }
            camera_device = device;
        }
        do {

            // Set up the camera image output
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera_device)
            if((capture_session?.canAddInput(input)) != nil) {
                capture_session?.addInput(input);
            }

            // Set up the camera video output
            video_output = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput();
            video_output?.movieFragmentInterval = kCMTimeInvalid;
            video_output?.maxRecordedDuration = CMTime(seconds: 10, preferredTimescale: 1);
            if((capture_session?.canAddOutput(video_output)) != nil) {
                capture_session?.addOutput(video_output);
                preview_layer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: capture_session);
                preview_layer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
                preview_layer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait;
                self.camera_view.layer.addSublayer(preview_layer!);
                preview_layer!.frame = self.view.bounds;
            }

            // Set up camera audio output
            let audio_device: AVCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)
            let audio_input: AVCaptureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audio_device)
            if((capture_session?.canAddInput(audio_input)) != nil) {
                capture_session?.addInput(audio_input)
            }
            try self.camera_device!.lockForConfiguration()
            self.camera_device!.subjectAreaChangeMonitoringEnabled = true;
            self.camera_device!.unlockForConfiguration()

            // Focus camera when camera moves
            let subjectAreaDidChangeBlock = {(notification: NSNotification) -> Void in
                self.focus_camera();
            }
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil, usingBlock: subjectAreaDidChangeBlock)

            // Done
            capture_session?.commitConfiguration();
        } catch _ { }
    }
```

Then I use the following code to start recording:

```
       // Record
       if let video_connection = self.video_output?.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {

            // Start recording the video
            let recordingDelegate:AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate = self;
            let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
            let filePath = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("recorded.mov")
            if(selfie) {
                video_connection.automaticallyAdjustsVideoMirroring = false;
                video_connection.videoMirrored = true;
            }

            // Video Orientation
            video_connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait;
            if(self.orientation == "PortraitUpsideDown") {
                video_connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown;
            }
            else if(self.orientation == "LandscapeLeft") {
                video_connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeRight;
            }
            else if(self.orientation == "LandscapeRight") {
                video_connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
            }
            video_output!.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(filePath, recordingDelegate: recordingDelegate);
        }
```

Then I stop the video recording using the following code:

```
        // Stop recording
        self.video_output!.stopRecording();

        // Stop the camera
        self.capture_session?.stopRunning();
        self.preview_layer?.connection.enabled = false;
        self.capture_session = nil;
```

I can't seem to find any problems in my code. Can anyone suggest where I may be going wrong? Do I do something while recording the video or setting up the camera such that the camera preview layer starts freezing and audio stops recording randomly? What am I missing?

Some weird things that happen:

1. If I put the app in the background and come back, the camera unfreezes/starts recording audio again.
2. The camera stops recording audio only after the first time I record something.
3. The camera starts freezing the preview layer only after the first time I record something, however it happens sometimes and sometimes it doesn't.
4. I'm wondering if this is a multi-thread issue but I don't know exactly what to do about that?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Any updates on this? I have the same issue.

Comment: Did you got any solution? Please Help!